# Magento - only some categories slow load

Tags: magento, load

I have a problem with my Magento store. Some categories are loading quickly and some are loading minutes, or doesn´t load.

If I make a new category and put all products from slow loading category, everything works perfectly.

Where is the problem ?

For example:

[This is loading perfectly](http://najdarcek.sk/plysove-darceky2)

[This will not load](http://najdarcek.sk/plysove-darceky)

But the categories are the same, with same products and setup.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run reindex? Try to run reindex and let me know your result